# Unable to create reference of HDF5 dataset in Python

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am using the HDF5 python lib h5py and want to create a reference from an HDF5 dataset by

```
ref = DATASET.regionref[:, :, 0]
```

However, I receive an error

```
 ValueError: Unable to create reference (No write intent on file)
```

In fact, I haven't and don't want to open the file with write access. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems h5py does not allow region references if the file isn't opened with write access. The reason may be that these references act as numpy arrays [allowing reading and writing](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/refs.html#refs-region).

I didn't find much mentioning of region references in the HDF5 [format specification](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.format.html), so I guess one could in principle make them read only. This might be a possible request for enhancement for h5py.

For the time being I would rather use views/slices on the numpy array directly if that is okay with your needs.